# c#: pulse and wait

Tags: c#, monitor

I have a question regarding the pulse and wait of monitor class. Following is the extract of code. My question is will the code be stuck at

> **// <<-----------**

untill **locker** becomes free ?

```
     {
        check = false;
        new Thread(pulseWaitFun).Start();

        Console.Writeline("Threading tutorial");

        lock (locker) // <<-----------
        {
            check = true;
            Monitor.Pulse(locker);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void pulseWaitFun()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if(check != true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(20000);
                Monitor.Wait(locker);

            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Woken !!");
    }
```

second question, after `Monitor.Pulse(locker);` what will be following sequence of execution ?

Comment: Just take a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28785/Thread-synchronization-Wait-and-Pulse-demystified

Comment: No its not. Just to clear my concepts !

Comment: @user2140086 to understand it better you should _explode_ the lock to its implementation (try/finally with Monitor.Enter/Monitor.Exit), that syntax at first may be confusing

Comment: @Nolonar, So? What if it is homework? The question is clear and it's a good question. Shouldn't matter if it's homework or not IMHO.

Comment: @FilipEkberg If it is homework, the OP should have all materials/references needed to find the answer without any outside help. **If** it is homework indeed, which it apparently isn't. Besides, if you think the question is good, you should upvote it.

Comment: @Nolonar, I consider internet being a source of material/references for homework, always have and when I teach my students something and give them homework I expect them to use internet to explore the possibilites. This might be homework but it might also not be, he might just want to learn something that is not in the curricilum.

I did upvote it because I think it's a valid question, even if it is quite poorly asked, but you can't always have everything..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My q is will the code be stuck at ... untill locker becomes free ?

Yes, but the lock can be released by exiting a `lock() {}` block *OR* by entering a `Wait()`.

> after Monitor.Pulse(locker); what will be following sequence of execution ?

In your code the sequence will most likely be:

1. `Thread(pulseWaitFun).Start();`
2. `lock (locker)` , uncontested so the lock is immediately granted
3. `Monitor.Pulse(locker);` , the Pulse is wasted because nobody is waiting.
4. exit `lock()` in the main method
5. The 2nd Thread starts executing...

You probably want a `Thread.Sleep(100)` inside Main(), after starting the Thread.

Comment: So if I have `Thread.Sleep(100)` after starting the thread inside main then will this order of executed mentioned by you change ?

Comment: @Henk In his special case with Console.Writeline after Start, pulseWaitFun gets executed first and locks.

Comment: @Alex - probably. What I should have emphasized is that it's non-deterministic.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes indeed, since you never really know when the thread gets sheduled.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assume which of locks will be invoked first. Let us consider two options:

- Lock in main method is reached first. Check is set to true. Invoking Pulse has no effect. Next main thread releases the lock and the second thread can aquire it in pulseWaitFun.
- Lock in pulseWaitFun method is reached first. Check is false, so thread is sleeping and then waits for signal which causes realising the lock. Now the main thread aquires the lock and pulses. Then releases the lock. After that pulseWaitFun can proceed.